# Display Progress C

Tags: c, progress-bar, progressdialog

so i read data like this

```
if (contentLengthType == CONTENTLEN_EXIST) {
        printf("Content-Length = %lu\n", contentLength);
    }
{

    int fd = open(dst, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0777);
    int total_read = 0;
    if (fd < 0) {
        return fd;
    }

    while (1) {
        int read = readData(req, buf, sizeof(buf));
        if (read < 0) {
            return read;
        }
        if (read == 0)
            break;
        ret = write(fd, buf, read);
        if (ret < 0 || ret != read) {
            if (ret < 0)
                return ret;
            return -1;
        }
        total_read += read;
    }
```

However id like it to display write progress based on content-length using my progress bar as seen here int32_t progress_steps = 10; im not sure how to display progress

Comment: You should add in which environment you want to display anything? GTK+, QT, shell, MFC,...

Comment: Just printf would be good and ill add in the progress bar API in place of printf but just need to know *how* first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to calculate which part of the total length was read so far and scale to the desired value for displaying a progress indication.

Of course this only works if you have the content length available which you check in your first `if`.

Basically it boils down to some basic math exercise that you have to execute in each round of the loop.

```
#define PROGRESS_STEPS 10.0

// calculate part of total task in range 0.0..10.0
float progress = (float)total_read / content_length * PROGRESS_STEPS;

// Apply some rounding according to personal preferences

// Print current progress indicator
printf("%d/%d\n", (int) progress, (int) PROGRESS_STEPS);
// Depending on terminal you might add code to use same line for each output.
```